# как сделать смещение тени

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.price-block {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between; }

.price-block__text {
  color: #282828;
  font-family: "SFUI Text";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400; }

.price-block__text2 {
  display: block;
  color: #282828;
  font-family: "SFUI Text";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px; }

.btn-price {
  background-color: #c9a461;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "SFUI Text";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px -6px 1px red;
          box-shadow: 6px -6px 1px red; }
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="img/price-img1.png" alt="">
  <div class="price-block">
    <span class="price-block__text">
      Президентский люкс
      <span class="price-block__text2">
        15 000 руб.
      </span>
    </span>
    <button class="btn-price">
    Подробнее
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Сейчас тень смещается вправо и вверх
2. А надо вправо и вниз
3. пробовал 2 параметру прописать положительное число ничего не получилось ?

Comment: Всё получилось.

Comment: @Qwertiy Здравствуйте тень красная идет вверх и вправо, а надо вниз и вправо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> box-shadow: 6px -6px 1px red;
> ```

```
box-shadow: 6px 6px 1px red;
```

Comment: понял в чем была проблема надо было пространство кнопке дать